# Google Sheets queries: using WHERE IN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

## My problem

I have a table of `id`s and `term`s in Google Sheets. I would like to concatenate a few terms by their ids.

For example, `(2,3)` should yield `Talla de zapato de mujer, Women’s shoe size`. I want to take id list from a separate cell.

[image]

So, I tried:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A,B WHERE A=2 OR A=3")
```

[image]

The query works fine, but it's hard to manually extract the 2's and 3's this way.

So I tried:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A,B WHERE A IN (2,3)")
```

Which does not work (`VALUE` error).

## My question

How can I select ids from a table using a GSheets query using a few ids written in a different cell?

Answer (score 9):

The `=QUERY()` language [`WHERE`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) clause support regex; so you can "simulate" IN functionality using a regex group - ie:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A,B WHERE A MATCHES '(2|3)'")
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep away the ID's use

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT B WHERE A=2 OR A=3")
```

Then to get `Talla de zapato de mujer, Women’s shoe size` you could use

```
=JOIN(", ", QUERY(A:B, "SELECT B WHERE A=2 OR A=3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [David Laing's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124401/292394), I managed to get the query with a separate range of IDs working with a `join` like this:

`QUERY(Transactions!$B5:$E, join("", "SELECT C WHERE C > 0 AND NOT E MATCHES '(", join("|", B28:B44), ")'"))`

It joins the IDs using a pipe character `join("|", B28:B44)`, and then joins the whole query string together with an empty string, `join("", "SELECT C WHERE ... '(", join("|", B28:B44), ")'")`

It might be hard to read because of all the quotes, but it should not require hard coded IDs within the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions but found that it only worked when the length of the list was known. I wanted to be able to look up values in an entire column. I modified [dstuessy's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/163347) as follows.

First I created a query which creates the joined list of the values you are looking for, with | pipe symbol as a delimiter like this:

```
   =JOIN("|", QUERY(C2:C, "SELECT C WHERE C IS NOT NULL"))
```

This can go in a separate cell (say cell F2) and returns the list of IDs like 2|3.

You then query the main database checking for  MATCHES in the F2 cell as in [David Laing's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124401).

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"SELECT B WHERE A MATCHES '"& F2 &"'   ",1)
```

If you don't want the F2 Helper cell you can roll it all into 1 query like this:

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"SELECT B WHERE A MATCHES '"&      JOIN("|", QUERY(C2:C, "SELECT C WHERE C IS NOT NULL"))        &"'   ",1)
```